# Cobol number format

Tags: sas, cobol

I have no experience with COBOL but one of the programs that I need to read in the mainframe with SAS is written in COBOL and I see fields like the following:

Amount
0000000084{
0000000433F

how can I read this data using SAS commands?

Thanks

Comment: No idea, but Cobol number formats are defined like `AMOUNT    PIC S9(6)V99 COMP-3` in the code, so I guess you'll need to find the Usage definition in the source. Also, it appears you may be dealing with an EBCDIC->ASCII fail.

Comment: Are you running on the Mainframe ???. The 084{ looks to be a Zoned decimal (Cobol Pic s9999. field). You will need to get the cobol copybook to interpret the data correctly. Try googling SAS cobol. The first entry http://support.sas.com/kb/3/714.html seems to have some relavent info

Comment: Why would you be reading a COBOL program in SAS? Make your question as clear as possible, please. Are you running SAS on the Mainframe or off? So, what OS? Those look like two packed-decimal fields, one signed, one not. However, you do need to look at the record-description as any decimal places are implicit. Why have you picked on that data as two fields? It could be multiple binary fields, so what were you give which tells you that is just two fields?

Comment: That is not an EBCDIC->ASCII fail, that is zoned decimal, the low digit contains the sign in the high nibble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SAS format for these two fields would beL

```
INPUT @08 firstNum zd11.
      @20 secondNum zd11.
```

This will define "firstNum" and "secondNum" as the zoned data in the line below:

```
Amount 0000000084{ 0000000433F
```

I'm assuming the "Amount" started at position one, otherwise you would need to adjust your positioning.

Comment: If they have an implied decimal, the format string is like "zd9.2" instead of "zd11".

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with it, but PROC COPYLIB is a SAS procedure that will read
any valid COBOL record layout and produce the
following:

1) Generate an equivalent input statement for
the processed COBOL record layout.

2) A SAS dataset containing a description of
the COBOL record layout. This data set can
be used as a data dictionary.

3) COBOL Record Layout Report -- which details
the COBOL record layout including the
starting position, length, and type for
each field within the FD.

4) COBOL/SAS Conversion Report -- which
matches the COBOL FD to the generated SAS
input statement.